# Edit distance function

Tags: c++, edit-distance

Could you please help me to review my first function (modified from an example) in terms of best practice, coding style suggestions and any obvious language mistake/improvements?

```
unsigned int edit_distance(const vector<string> &s1, const vector<string> &s2)
{
    const size_t len1 = s1.size(), len2 = s2.size();
    vector<vector<unsigned int>> d(len1 + 1, vector<unsigned int>(len2 + 1));

    d[0][0] = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= len1; ++i) d[i][0] = i;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= len2; ++i) d[0][i] = i;

    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= len1; ++i)
            for(unsigned int j = 1; j <= len2; ++j)
            {
                unsigned int a = d[i - 1][j] + 1;
                unsigned int b = d[i][j - 1] + 1;
                unsigned int c = d[i - 1][j - 1] + (s1[i - 1] == s2[j - 1] ? 0 : 1);
                        d[i][j] = std::min( std::min(a,b), c);
            }
    return d[len1][len2];
}
```

Comment: For starters you need a function comment, explain what its doing, use readable variable names. You don't get any performance improvement from minified code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want `unsigned int` or do you want `std::size_t`?

```
unsigned int edit_distance(const vector<string> &s1, const vector<string> &s2)
```

It comes down to what you are trying to convey.
The use of `string` and `vector` suggests you are doing `using namespace std;` try [not to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/14065). Prefer to qualify your types: `std::string` and `std::vector`.

Personally, I prefer `const` on the right. But it's only a preference thing.

Only declare one variable per line:

```
    const size_t len1 = s1.size(), len2 = s2.size();
```

Come up with better names. `d` is not very descriptive.

```
    vector<vector<unsigned int>> d(len1 + 1, vector<unsigned int>(len2 + 1));
```

I would prefer `std::size_t` here:

```
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= len1; ++i) d[i][0] = i;
```